# In Excel, how to apply graded color scale (with conditional formatting) only if cell value is greater than 5?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, colors, conditional-formatting

Suppose I have this dataset (the variable is not important in this case)
[image]

I would like to add a color scale for `% Missing` column, with light red being the lowest value and dark red being the highest value. However, I only want to do this if the cell value is greater or equal to 5. Is this possible? I can't find a way to do this through conditional formatting. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done by applying two Conditional Formatting rules to the same range.

- First a **Format all cells based on their values** rule, using the ***3-Color Scale*** with the red colors
- Then a **Format only cells that contain** rule, using ***Cell Value*** > ***less than or equal to*** > ***=5***
  [image]

Comment: This does the trick! Thank you very much. Do you happen to also know if this is possible if I try to scale the colors based on values in another column?

Comment: Certainly no "normal" way to do that. Maybe with VBA etc.